# Javascript change font color

Tags: javascript

I need to change the font color.

I have the following:

```
   var clr="green";

    <font color=clr>' + onlineff + ' </font>
```

The font color does not change to green. Just wondering how this could be fixed.

Comment: presentational tags like <font>, <center>,... should be avoided at all (markup should be used for semantic purpose only). Use `style` attribute instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `<font color=`. It's a really old fashioned way to style text and some browsers even don't even support it anymore.

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Cfont%3E) lists it as obsolete, and strongly recommends not using the `<font>` tag. The same is with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

> Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5.
>
> Starting with HTML 4, HTML does not convey styling information anymore (outside the  element or the style attribute of each element). For any new web development, styling should be written using CSS only.
>
> The former behavior of the  element can be achieved, and even better controlled using the CSS Fonts CSS properties.

If we look at when the 4.01 standard was published we see it was published in 1999

[image: published html5 standard]

where `<font>` was [officially deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT), meaning it is still supported but shouldn't be used anymore as it will go away in the newer standard.

And in the [html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) standard released in August 2014 it was deemed obsolete and non conforming.

To achieve the desired effect use spans and css:

```js
function givemecolor(thecolor,thetext)
{
    return '<span style="color:'+thecolor+'">'+thetext+'</span>';
}
document.write(givemecolor('green',"Hello, I'm green"));
document.write(givemecolor('red',"Hello, I'm red"));
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

**update**

This question and answer are from 2012 and now I wouldn't recommend using document.write as it needs to be executed when the document is rendered first time. I had used it back then because I assumed OP was wishing to use it in such a way. I'd recommend using a more conventional way to insert the custom elements you wish to use, at the place you wish to insert them, without relying on document rendering and when and where the script is executed.

Native:

```js
function givemecolor(thecolor,thetext)
{
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.color = thecolor;
    span.innerText = thetext;
    return span;
}
var container = document.getElementById('textholder');
container.append(givemecolor('green', "Hello I'm green"));
container.append(givemecolor('red', "Hello I'm red"));
```

```css
body {
 background: #333;
 color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h1> some title </h1>
<div id="textholder">
</div>
<p> some other text </p>
```

jQuery

```js
function givemecolor(thecolor, thetext)
{
    var $span = $("<span>");
    $span.css({color:thecolor});
    $span.text(thetext);
    return $span;
}
var $container = $('#textholder');
$container.append(givemecolor('green', "Hello I'm green"));
$container.append(givemecolor('red', "Hello I'm red"));
```

```css
body {
 background: #333;
 color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> some title </h1>
<div id="textholder">
</div>
<p> some other text </p>
```

Comment: @BenBarden That's an apostrophe.

Answer (score 17):

Consider changing your markup to this:

```
<span id="someId">onlineff</span>
```

Then you can use this script:

```
var x = document.getElementById('someId');
x.style.color = '#00FF00';
```

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ANmM/

Answer (score 5):

Html code

```
<div id="coloredBy">
    Colored By Santa
</div>
```

javascript code

```
document.getElementById("coloredBy").style.color = colorCode; // red or #ffffff
```

I think this is very easy to use

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var clr = 'green';
var html = '<font color="' + clr + '">' + onlineff + ' </font>';
```

This being said, you should avoid using the `<font>` tag. It is now deprecated. Use CSS to change the style (color) of a given element in your markup.

Comment: it's not deprecated it's *removed* (and there is no `color` attribute either).

Comment: `font` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/font) since html 4.01

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML tag in order to apply font size, font color in one line on JavaScript, as well as you can use `.fontcolor()` method to define color, `.fontsize()` method to define the font size, `.bold()` method to define bold, etc. These are called [JavaScript Built-in Functions --> String HTML Wrappers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_builtin_functions.htm).

- Here is a list of some JavaScript built-in functions:

.big()
.small()
.italics()
.fixed()
.strike()
.sup()

- Below some built-in functions require parameters:

.fontsize() //e.g.: the size to be applied in number `.fontsize(4)`

.fontcolor("") //e.g.: the color to be applied in string `.fontcolor("red")`

.txt.link("") //e.g.: the url to be linkable as string `.link("www.test.com")`

.toUpperCase() //e.g.: the converted to uppercase to be applied in string `.toUpperCase()`

- Remember the syntax is: `string.functionName()` e.g.:

`var txt = "Hello World!"; txt.bold();`

- This also can be done in one line:

  `var txt = "Hello World!".bold();`

The result will be: **Hello World!**

- You can use multiple built-in functions in one line, adding one next to the other. e.g.:

  "10/22/2018".fontcolor("red").fontsize(4).bold()
- The following is an example how I used it on my JavaScript code to change font  (color, size, bold) using both HTML tags and JavaScript functions:

> `vForm.message = "<HTML><font size = 4 color = 'red'><b> Application Deadline was </b></font></HTML> "  + "10/22/2018".fontcolor("red").fontsize(4).bold(); /* setting HTML font color, size, bold and combined them with JavaScript functions to change font  color, size, bold in JavaScript code */`

- Here is the result:

> **[image: Application Deadline was 10/22/2018]**