# how can i change attribute of a creating element

Tags: javascript, createelement

I create an element e.g. `a`.

```
alink=document.createElement("a");
```

then I set the Attribute:

```
alink.setAttribute("style","border: 0px;");
alink.setAttribute("style","color: red;");
...
```

Now I want to change the attribute after the insert.

when I create this element I insert it into an iframe. So is it possible to change the attribute after the insert?

I can read the attributes like `document.getElementById("link").href` but how can I change the attribute (styles) like `color` or `font-size` .......

Comment: Colors and font sizes are not attributes. They are CSS properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript change font color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982489/javascript-change-font-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors and font sizes are not attributes. They are CSS properties.

For example you have inserted your link into the document:

```
var alink = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(alink);
```

Then you do the following to set its `style` attribute:

```
//Case one
alink.setAttribute("style","border: 0px;");
alink.setAttribute("style","color: red;");
```

Wrong! Don't do this. Instead, do this:

```
//Case two
alink.style.border = 0;
alink.style.color = "red";
```

Now this will work as expected.

Comment: Its do easy. Thx. Why i dont have to use setAttribute?

Comment: @StefanGum Again, CSS properties are not attributes. It doesn't make sense to use `setAttribute` anyway and it will overwrite any pre-existing inline CSS that you have assigned.

Comment: Ok Thx for your help