# Why is .fontcolor() still not declared obsolete?

Tags: javascript

I edited an old answer of mine to bring it more up to date, and I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071185/1356107). And I thought by myself surely that wouldn't work anymore. The font tag itself has been declared obsolete since 2014.

But, after putting the code in my browsers console it still worked to my surprise.

```js
console.log("some text".fontcolor("red").fontsize(4).bold());
```

In the latest chrome:

[image: chrome console]

latest firefox:

[image: firefox console]

latest edge

[image: edge console]

Looking at MDN I see that [fontcolor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor) and [fontsize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontsize) are deprecated, when will they officially become obsolete, is a timeline known or documented somewhere? As the code they generate is not to current html5 spec. Or will browsers support them indefinitely as to stay html 3.2/4.01 compliant?

Comment: There are the HTML specs, then there is the implementation of this spec on every browser. My guess is that no browser wants to lose compatibility with legacy codes. Can you imagine one website on two crash because of one old plugin is crashing due to a `.fontcolor` call ? In my opinion, the method will stay available for a long time. Also, note that the doc say it's `deprecated` and have a note saying ` The <font> element has been removed in HTML5 and shouldn't be used anymore. Instead web developers should use CSS properties.`. If you still use it in 2020, it's something!

Comment: In the [ECMA standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) these methods are considered obsoloted, but "_web browsers must continue to support them_".

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT In some browsers contenteditables are still  producing these tags like `<font>` .